# BIRT report for lists of lists

Tags: birt

I'm a bit of a BIRT newbie, and I could really do with a hand.

Some background:

I'm developing some software which allows display and simple modelling of Layer 1 connectivity in a data centre.

This is Java based, running on Tomcat, using BIRT reports. BIRT fetches the data from a general web-service we've implemented, serving data up as XML, which BIRT fetches using SOAP.

The report I'm working on currently queries our system to find out the circuit trace on a particular port on a piece of equipment.

The simple report for this works fine. It gives an ancestry path to the assets, and then the specific asset and port.

For example, asset ID 49345, port 1 would result in a report that looks (a bit) like this...

```
Organization >> Comms Room >> Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01 >> Comms Room C02 R01 Telephone Patch Panel       P1 - B1
Organization >> Comms Room >> Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01 >> Comms Room C02 R01 Patch Panel 02              P2 - B2
Organization >> Client/Server development >> U1 ClntSvr FB 02 >> U1 ClntSvr FB 02 I4                          P2 - B2
```

This says that the back of the telephone patch panel goes to the front, via a patch cord to another panel, to the back of that panel, to the back of a floor box.

This report works quite happily.

One customer wants more!

They want the Excel export from the BIT report to be filterable, i.e. rather than having a delimited ancestry path, they need it in a list form, so when it's exported to Excel, each entry is on a different column.

I've modified my query to return an array of ancestry elements rather than a single string, and in its own way, this also works.

The SOAP response for this new query is below (for information - it may help)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <FindCircuitByAssetAndPortResponse>
         <CircuitDetail>
            <FoundByAsset>Comms Room C02 R01 Telephone Patch Panel (id: 49345)</FoundByAsset>
            <FoundByPort>P1</FoundByPort>
            <CircuitAssetDetail>
               <AssetId>49345</AssetId>
               <AncestryPath>Organization >> Comms Room >> Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01 >> Comms Room C02 R01 Telephone Patch Panel</AncestryPath>
               <AncestryPathList>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Organization</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Comms Room</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Comms Room C02 R01 Telephone Patch Panel</AncestryPathElement>
               </AncestryPathList>
               <AssetTypeName>Patch Panel</AssetTypeName>
               <InPort>B1</InPort>
               <OutPort>P1</OutPort>
            </CircuitAssetDetail>
            <CircuitAssetDetail>
               <AssetId>49339</AssetId>
               <AncestryPath>Organization >> Comms Room >> Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01 >> Comms Room C02 R01 Patch Panel 02</AncestryPath>
               <AncestryPathList>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Organization</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Comms Room</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Comms Room C02 R01 Patch Panel 02</AncestryPathElement>
               </AncestryPathList>
               <AssetTypeName>Patch Panel</AssetTypeName>
               <InPort>P2</InPort>
               <OutPort>B2</OutPort>
            </CircuitAssetDetail>
            <CircuitAssetDetail>
               <AssetId>48634</AssetId>
               <AncestryPath>Organization >>  Client/Server development >> U1 ClntSvr FB 02 >> U1 ClntSvr FB 02 I4</AncestryPath>
               <AncestryPathList>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Organization</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>Client/Server development</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>U1 ClntSvr FB 02</AncestryPathElement>
                  <AncestryPathElement>U1 ClntSvr FB 02 I4</AncestryPathElement>
               </AncestryPathList>
               <AssetTypeName>Module</AssetTypeName>
               <InPort>P2</InPort>
               <OutPort>B2</OutPort>
            </CircuitAssetDetail>
         </CircuitDetail>
      </FindCircuitByAssetAndPortResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The report data set uses the deepest layer, i.e. the ancestry elements.

When it displays the data though, there is duplicated data. For example, the data above is now shown as...

```
Organization                             B1 - P1
Comms Room                               B1 - P1
Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01            B1 - P1
Comms Room C02 R01 Telephone Patch Panel B1 - P1
Organization                             P2 - B2
Comms Room                               P2 - B2
Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01            P2 - B2
Comms Room C02 R01 Patch Panel 02        P2 - B2
Organization                             P2 - B2
Client/Server development                P2 - B2
U1 ClntSvr FB 02                         P2 - B2
U1 ClntSvr FB 02 I4                      P2 - B2
```

This is "correct" in that we're getting back 12 "rows" via XML. The column mapping says that the element is the "current" data, the ports (P1 & B1) are "up" one level, and so on.

If I fetch the data with respect to the ancestry path list, we don't get duplicated data, but at this point, the ancestry path list isn't seen as a list, so either displays nothing at all, or just the first element from the list repeatedly, resulting in...

```
Organization B1 - P1
Organization
Organization
Organization
Organization P2 - B2
Organization
Organization
Organization
Organization P2 - B2
Organization
Organization
Organization
```

I'm 99% sure BIRT will do what I need, but I'm a newcomer to it, and I'm surprised I've got as far as I have!

This problem is non-specific, as we have other situations where we may need to fetch lists of lists.

My apologies if this has already been covered. I have looked, but it may be listed under terminology I'm not familiar with.

Many thanks.

Pete.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the output you would like to see?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output like this

```
Organization                             B1 - P1
Comms Room                               
Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01           
Comms Room C02 R01 Telephone Patch Panel 
Organization                             P2 - B2
Comms Room                               
Comms Room Cabinet 02 Rack 01            
Comms Room C02 R01 Patch Panel 02        
Organization                            
Client/Server development                
U1 ClntSvr FB 02                        
U1 ClntSvr FB 02 I4
```

In BIRT there is a option called `GROUP` for this you have to do is 
select the table and you will have the properties dialog in there you will have `group options` and in that options it will list out the column names of your query and you can select your own column to group
[view this tutorial for grouping](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/examples/reports/GroupingReport/GroupingReport.html)